# Tex4ht error when trying to include more complex html

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, make4ht

I'm trying to change the MathJax font used by Tex4ht to AMS Euler, which can be done by including the following code on a webpage

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
var font = "Neo-Euler";
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$','$']],
        displayMath: [['\\[','\\]']],
        processEscapes: true,
    },
    "SVG":{ 
        font:font
    },
    "HTML-CSS": {
        webFont: font,
        imageFont: font,
        preferredFont: font,
        availableFonts: [],
        scale: 85,
        mtextFontInherit: true
    }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

However, if I try to insert this within an `\HCode` instruction, I get these errors

```
\Configure{@HEAD}{\endparagraph\HCode{
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  var font = "Neo-Euler";
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$','$']],
      displayMath: [['\\[','\\]']],
      processEscapes: true,
    },
    "SVG":{
      font:font
    },
    "HTML-CSS": {
      webFont: font,
      imageFont: font,
      preferredFont: font,
      availableFonts: [],
      scale: 85,
      mtextFontInherit: true
    }
  }); </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
}}
```

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./config/html.cfg    149      Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./config/html.cfg    149      Paragraph ended before \reserved@a was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    60       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Argument of \g:Advance has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Paragraph ended before \g:Advance was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Argument of \g:Advance has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Paragraph ended before \g:Advance was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Argument of \g:Advance has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Paragraph ended before \g:Advance was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Argument of \g:Advance has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Paragraph ended before \g:Advance was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Argument of \g:Advance has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Paragraph ended before \g:Advance was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Argument of \g:Advance has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Paragraph ended before \g:Advance was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Argument of \g:Advance has an extra }.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Paragraph ended before \g:Advance was complete.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Undefined control sequence.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    68       Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition.
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

I figured embedding the code inside a `\verb||` might help, but that caused a different issue.

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename     Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    150      TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
[FATAL]   make4ht-lib: Fatal error. Command htlatex returned exit code 1
```

My full config file is

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

% add tufte.css to your document
\Configure{AddCss}{/tufte.css}

\Configure{MathjaxSource}
{}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\endparagraph\HCode{
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  var font = "Neo-Euler";
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$','$']],
      displayMath: [['\\[','\\]']],
      processEscapes: true,
    },
    "SVG":{
      font:font
    },
    "HTML-CSS": {
      webFont: font,
      imageFont: font,
      preferredFont: font,
      availableFonts: [],
      scale: 85,
      mtextFontInherit: true
    }
  }); </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
}}

% helper macro to close the current paragraph
\def\endparagraph{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}

% insert <article> element to the document body
\Configure{@BODY}{\endparagraph\HCode{<article>}}
\Configure{@/BODY}{\endparagraph\HCode{</article>}}

% Tufte LaTeX makes \section and \subsection to behave like \section* and \subsection*
% so we need to configure like<section level>
% These configurations insert <section> elements and print titles in apropriate header elements
\Configure{likesection}
{\endparagraph\HCode{<section>}}{\endparagraph\HCode{</section>}}
{\HCode{<h2>}}{\HCode{</h2>}\par\ShowPar}

\Configure{likesubsection}
{\endparagraph\HCode{<section>}}{\endparagraph\HCode{</section>}}
{\HCode{<h3>}}{\HCode{</h3>}\par\ShowPar}

% we must redefine TOC to print starred sectioning commands
% \TableOfContents is provided by TeX4ht
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{\endparagraph\HCode{<h2>Contents</h2>\Hnewline}\TableOfContents[likesection,likesubsection]}

% custom \maketitle
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begingroup%
    \endparagraph\HCode{<h1>}\@title\HCode{</h1>}%
    \HCode{<p class="subtitle">}\@author\HCode{</p>}%
    \HCode{<p class="subtitle">}\@date\HCode{</p>}%
  \endgroup
}

% make images resize automatically
\Configure{Gin-dim}{}
\Css{img {
    max-width: 100\%;
    height: auto;
}}

% fix for commands redefined by soul
\@ifpackageloaded{soul}{%
\renewcommand{\allcaps}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}%
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}%
\renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\textcaps{#1}}%
}{}

% footnotes and sidenotes

\long\def\@tufte@sidenote[#1][#2]#3{%
  \stepcounter\@mpfn%
\bgroup% make font changes local
  \HCode{<label for="sitenote-\thempfn" class="margin-toggle sidenote-number"></label><input type="checkbox" id="sidenote-\thempfn" class="margin-toggle" />}%
  \HCode{<span class="sidenote">}#3\HCode{</span>}%
\egroup%
}
\renewcommand\marginnote[2][0pt]{%
  \stepcounter\@mpfn%
\bgroup% make font changes local
  \HCode{<label for="sitenote-\thempfn" class="margin-toggle"></label><input type="checkbox" id="sidenote-\thempfn" class="margin-toggle" />}%
  \HCode{<span class="marginnote">}#2\HCode{</span>}%
\egroup%
}

% environments

\ConfigureEnv{verbatim}{\endparagraph\HCode{<pre><code>}\NoFonts}{\EndNoFonts\endparagraph\HCode{</code></pre>}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{fullwidth}{\endparagraph\HCode{<div class="fullwidth">}%
\ConfigureList{list}{}{}{}{}% fullwidth uses list environment internally, we don't need this
\par\ShowPar\indent% require insertion of paragraph
}
{\endparagraph\HCode{</div>}}{}{}

% floats

\NewConfigure{marginfloat}{2}

% redefine internal margin float environment in order to prevent use of minipage and other undersirable environments
\renewenvironment{@tufte@margin@float}[2][-1.2ex]%
{\FloatBarrier% process all floats before this point so the figure/table numbers stay in order.
\begingroup%
\let\textwidth\marginparwidth% \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...} should work
\def\@captype{#2}%
\par%
% redefine paragraph
\Configure{HtmlPar}{\EndP\csname a:marginfloat\endcsname}{\EndP\csname a:marginfloat\endcsname}{\csname b:marginfloat\endcsname}{\csname b:marginfloat\endcsname}%
}
{\endgroup}

\Configure{marginfloat}{\HCode{<p><span class="marginnote">}
% we must handle \caption inside marginnote
\Configure{caption}{\HCode{<span class="figure">}}{:\space}{}{\HCode{</span>}}
}{\HCode{</span></p>}}{}{}

% display marginnote caption on a separate line
\Css{.marginnote .figure{display:block;}}

\renewenvironment{@tufte@float}[3][htbp]%
{\@float{#2}[#1]}{\end@float}

% caption should produce margin note by default
\Configure{caption}{\HCode{<span class="marginnote">}}{:\space}{}{\HCode{</span>}}

% figure* should produce full width image
% we need to make few adjustments
\ConfigureEnv{figure*}{
\Configure{float}{}{\endparagraph\HCode{<figure class="fullwidth">}}{\endparagraph\HCode{</figure>}\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}
\Configure{caption}{\endparagraph\HCode{<span class="figure">}}{:\space}{}{\HCode{</span>}}
}{}{}{}

\ConfigureEnv{margintable}{\endparagraph\HCode{<div class="margintable">}\Configure{caption}{}{:\space}{}{}}{\endparagraph\HCode{</div>}}{}{}

% fix for display math length
\Css{div.math-display, div.par-math-display {width: 55\%}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The $\LaTeX$ file in question can be found [here](https://paste.rs/U6D.tex).

Comment: Could you also add an example of your TeX file? I

Comment: I've added a link at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an issue with unwanted expansion in your MathJax config. You can  use `\detokenize` to prevent that:

```
\Configure{MathjaxSource}
{}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\endparagraph\HCode{
\detokenize{%
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  var font = "Neo-Euler";
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$','$']],
      displayMath: [['\\[','\\]']],
      processEscapes: true,
    },
    "SVG":{
      font:font
    },
    "HTML-CSS": {
      webFont: font,
      imageFont: font,
      preferredFont: font,
      availableFonts: [],
      scale: 85,
      mtextFontInherit: true
    }
  }); </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js"></script>
}}}

% helper macro to close the current paragraph
\def\endparagraph{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}
```

Note that I had to use a different address for MathJax, as the one you used no longer works. Also note that if you use up-to date TeX4ht, you can use `\Configure{MathJaxConfig}`:

```
\Configure{MathJaxConfig}{{ 
\detokenize{
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$','$']],
      displayMath: [['\\[','\\]']],
      processEscapes: true,
    },
    "SVG":{
      font:"Neo-Euler"
    },
    "HTML-CSS": {
      webFont: "Neo-Euler",
      imageFont: "Neo-Euler",
      preferredFont: "Neo-Euler",
      availableFonts: [],
      scale: 85,
      mtextFontInherit: true
    }
  } 
}}
```

It is available when you use `make4ht filename.tex "mathjax"` option.

In any case, it seems that the Euler font is not used anyway:

[image]